# how to sync local and remote database Angular 4?

Tags: database, angular

Fist, sorry for my bad English.

I am new with Angular 4, and need make an aplication (web, or desk with electron), with a remote database for external users querys in the web, but Administrative users need to continue working in case of losing the connection, have a practical way to sync in this case?

Firebase? Mysql? Local database?

Thanks Guys